# Compute the integral $\int_0^\infty t^{3/\xi-1} e^{-t} \Gamma(\frac{2}{\xi},t) \ dt$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function, beta-function

Hopefully this is my last question of this kind... I've tried this in several different ways, but I always end up stuck in a loop of iterative integration by parts and proving 1 = 1.
As important a proof this is for fundamental mathematics, it isn't what I am after unfortunately... Here's the integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty t^{3/\xi-1} e^{-t} \Gamma(\tfrac{2}{\xi},t) \ dt.
$$

For information: $\xi$ is real and positive.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @metamorphy That could work. Can you give me a bit of direction into how you converted the integral into that form? If I can write it as an incomplete beta function, then I can rewrite it as a hypergeometric function and can restructure slightly.

Comment: Converted it into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only closed form I see is via the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function): $$\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}\,\Gamma(\beta,t)\,dt=\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)\,\mathrm{B}(1/2;\alpha,\beta),$$
obtained using the definition $\Gamma(\beta,t)=\int_t^\infty x^{\beta-1}e^{-x}\,dx$ and interchanging integrations:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}\,\Gamma(\beta,t)\,dt
&=\int_0^\infty x^{\beta-1}e^{-x}\int_0^x t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}\,dt\,dx
\\\color{gray}{[\text{substitute }t=xy]}
&=\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha+\beta-1}e^{-x}\int_0^1 y^{\alpha-1}e^{-xy}\,dy\,dx
\\\color{gray}{[\text{integrate over }x]}
&=\int_0^1 y^{\alpha-1}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{(1+y)^{\alpha+\beta}}\,dy
\\\color{gray}{[\text{substitute }y/(1+y)=t]}
&=\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)\int_0^{1/2}t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{\beta-1}\,dt.
\end{align}